# How to purchase apps through my personal AppleId and charge my employer?

Tags: icloud, ios-appstore

I'm trying to get my job to pay for apps i use on ios, in addition to icloud storage.

I can't see to find away to add another account that can purchase apps/services for me. Would appreciate any help on the matter: that is get my job to but the apps but use them on my personal phone/mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to adding someone else's or company's payment method to your own Apple ID, it's okay but look at your company's policies.
Go to setting, your Apple ID - Payment& SHipping - Add Payment Method, add a credit card debit card or Paypal as usual.

I personally think the best way is to buy a physical gift card and get an  receipt, then redeem the gift card on your Apple ID.

You can also choose to buy with other Apple IDs and send a gift to you own Apple ID. However, iCloud Apple music and other subscriptions are not available in this way.

Comment: In addition to this, you can also obtain the receipt from your iTunes Account and get compensated from the company's accounts department.